# Cannot Apply EF7 Migrations - Could not load file or assembly... because I might not know something about ASP.net 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-core

I currently have a web project to host database migrations. It was created off an Empty Website. I'm using .net Core only, but I don't think this matters. I'm referencing rc1, not beta. (At this point, I won't show you my project.json, my data context, or the startup.cs file because I think the issue isn't with those.)

I've managed adding a migration with the usual `dnx ef migrations add migrationName` command from the command prompt.

At the command prompt, I'm sitting at the directory of my web project. When I try to run `dnx ef database update`, I got

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject'..."
```

I built the project and it compiles without error. I'm accustomed to seeing a /bin folder that has assemblies, where one of the .dlls is MyProject.dll from ASP.net 4.5.x and before. I don't see this folder or such a .dll anywhere in the project. I think the dnx is looking for that but it doesn't exist.

Should I publish the project first? None of the tutorials out there tell me to do that. I tried to anyway, but even in the artifacts folder of the solution, I cannot find any .dlls besides those that come from Microsoft.

There must be something I'm missing or that tutorials don't say, though I'm aware that those tutorials are probably old.

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I needed to

1. Right-click on project > Build.
2. Check "Produce Output on Build". It is unchecked by default. Those tutorials didn't tell us this important bit of information!

After that, all is well! I was able to migrate to the database.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you were able to run `dnx ef migrations add` but not `dnx ef database update` from the same working directory?

Comment: I didn't make that very clear, but yes, I'm running both commands in the same directory. Tutorials don't tell me to switch directories for the update command.